# date pipe - bug or my mistake?

Tags: bash, date, pipe

I faced a strange behavior of the date command:

```
echo '1 JAN 2023' | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8  date -d -
```

This produces plainly wrong output:

```
Sun Jun 11 12:00:00 AM CEST 2023
```

But this is ok:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8  date -d '1 Jan 2023'  # Sun Jan  1 12:00:00 AM CET 2023
```

This is ok as well:

```
my_date='1 JAN 2023'
LC_ALL=en_US.utf8  date -d  "$my_date" # Sun Jan  1 12:00:00 AM CET 2023
```

I cannot get the pipe version working. Is a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `date` command's `--date` / `-d` option expects a *string argument* - the standard input is discarded, and `-` is parsed as a date input string according to the GNU `date` command's [General date syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-date-syntax.html), which says

> Hyphens not followed by a digit are currently ignored.

and

> The empty string means the beginning of today (i.e., midnight).

So your command is simply equivalent to `LC_ALL=en_US.utf8  date -d 'today 00:00'`.

To take input from a pipe, you'd either need to convert stdin to an argument - for example with `xargs`:

```
$ echo '1 JAN 2023' | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8  xargs -d '\n' date -d
Sun Jan  1 12:00:00 AM EST 2023
```

or ([as suggested by Raffa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1471890/date-pipe-bug-or-my-mistake#comment2579760_1471892)) by passing it through to a command that *does* read standard input, capturing that command's output in a *command substitution*:

```
$ echo '1 JAN 2023' | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8  date -d "$(cat -)"
Sun Jan  1 12:00:00 AM EST 2023
```

It's much simpler to use the `-f` option instead, which does read from standard input:

```
$ echo '1 JAN 2023' | LC_ALL=en_US.utf8  date -f -
Sun Jan  1 12:00:00 AM EST 2023
```

From `man date`:

```
   -f, --file=DATEFILE
          like --date; once for each line of DATEFILE
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that utilities that can read and *echo* from the pipe such as `cat` and `tee` should work as well in a command substitution syntax ... e.g. `echo '1 JAN 2023' | date -d "$(cat)"` and `echo '1 JAN 2023' | date -d "$(tee)"`

Comment: @Raffa thanks - done

Comment: Thank you all, I guess that "date -f - " is the best as it is no bashism, this is as it ought to work. (Stdin is a virtual file in fact.) It is nice to have so many smart people around, isn't it? :-)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what version of `date` are you using but `man date`
doesn't mention that when `-` is specified input is taken from
standard input:

```
$ echo something | date -d -
Sun Jun 11 00:00:00 CEST 2023
$ date -d -
Sun Jun 11 00:00:00 CEST 2023
```

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, `date` doesn't read from standard input; the `-d` option expects the date string in the next argument. You can use command substitution to put the output of a command there.

```
date -d "$(echo '1 JAN 2023')"
```